# How to override LESS colour variables without creating a new skin in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, css

I have a default MediaWiki install using the Vector skin.  I would like to change the colours, but I want to keep maintenance to a minimum so I don't want to duplicate the skin (because I will have to re-do this after every MW upgrade.)

The colours are defined in the Vector skin's `variables.less`, so I would like to effectively insert my own code at the end of this file, so that it gets processed in the conversion to CSS.

I tried putting my code in the MW article `MediaWiki:Vector.css` but this gets embedded into each page *after* the LESS to CSS conversion has been done, so it's too late to override LESS variables by then.

How can I alter the LESS variables for the Vector skin, without having to duplicate the whole Vector skin code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate file called `variables-overrides.less` and in there you override all the variables you need.

Next, you need to modify `variables.less` to include your overrides. Make sure you include this at the end of the `variables.less` file.

```
@import "variables-overrides.less"; //Include at end of variables.less
```

Next time you upgrade MediaWiki you just need to update the single line of code above.